# If $[G:H]=2$, then G is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So suppose $G$ is a group, and $H<G$.  If $[G:H]=2$, the $G$ is Abelian.

I know I have use Lagrange here (okay, maybe I don't know, but I'm pretty sure).  I DO know that $|G|=|[G:H]||H|$ which, if $|G|=n$ and $|H|=m$, then $\frac{|G|}{|H|}=2 \Rightarrow n=2m$.  Thus, for all $g\in G, g^n=e$ and for all $h\in H, h^m=e$.

But how does this get me to where i need to show that $gh=hg$?

$\mathbf{EDIT}$:  I review the problem, and it stands as is, but it never says "Prove"...  Here is the problem verbatim:

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $[G:H]=2$ then $G$ is Abelian.

So I suppose since it never says prove, then showing a counter example works just fine.

$\mathbf{EDIT 2}$  My computer is not allowing me to upvote or select answers, so thank you al for the help.  I understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: $G$ is not necessarily Abelian. Take $G=S_n$ and $H=A_n$.

Comment: I think you want to prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ instead?

Comment: Why does this question take upvote; even if it is wrong :)

Comment: How are questions wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A counter-example: $G=S_4, H=A_4.$ Then definitely $G$ is not abelian.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Besides to @Ludolila's leading comment, consider $S_3$, a non abelian well known group of order $6$. It is an extension of $\mathbb Z_3$ by $\mathbb Z_2$.